# Gtilab pipeline trigger don't work over webhook (returns 404)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-trigger

I have created a custom trigger form my project in GitLab and it works fine on branch 'main' via curl (with POST queries):

```
curl -X POST -F token=%myToken% -F ref=main https://%mygitlab%/api/v4/projects/82/trigger/pipeline
```

OR:

```
curl --request POST "https://%mygitlab%/api/v4/projects/82/trigger/pipeline?token=%myToken%&ref=main"
```

But I want to use webhook and try the next:

```
https://%mygitlab%/api/v4/projects/82/ref/main/trigger/pipeline?token=%myToken%
```

It doesn't work and returns 404:

```
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
```

What do I miss or do wrong? May be I must to configure something?

Answer (score 2):

Your webhook URL https://%mygitlab%/api/v4/projects/82/ref/main/trigger/pipeline?token=%myToken% should work (use the token from Settings->CI/CD->Pipeline triggers), but the webhook request must be http POST.

This is why

```
 curl https://%mygitlab%/api/v4/projects/82/ref/main/trigger/pipeline?token=%myToken%
```

will return 404, but

```
 curl -X POST https://%mygitlab%/api/v4/projects/82/ref/main/trigger/pipeline?token=%myToken%
```

will work. I have the same behavior on my GitLab (Self-Managed).

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find it because your repository is not public. You have to add the `token` parameter to login into your account so it is able to see your repo and succesfully trigger the pipeline.

The `token` parameter must contain an accessToken you generate in your personal gitlab account. Make sure you gave enough permission to the accessToken.

Also, instead of passing the ref in the url try:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/82/trigger/pipeline?token=%myToken%&ref=main
```

Comment: Where I must place acessToken in webhook url?

Comment: Try `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/82/trigger/pipeline?token=%myToken%&ref=main` replace `%myToken%` with your personal access token, that has sufficient access to the repo. That will do the job.

Comment: Trying with my personal access token - result is the same: 404.

Comment: Does the token have all permissions?

Comment: Yes. I checked everything. I found when I do not have acess rights gitlab returns { message, "404: not found}, and when I add access token It works. But in that case it returns { error, "404 not found" } (error, not message).

Comment: Also make sure the branch exists as well on the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

From gitlab's documentation, [trigger API doesn't support Personal Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/index.html#404-not-found-when-triggering-a-pipeline). To authenticate, there are two options: **Pipeline Trigger Tokens** or **CI Job tokens**.

There is documentation to add a new Pipeline Trigger Token at:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#adding-a-new-trigger

Basically, you have to go to your **Settings > CI/CD** under **Pipelines Triggers** to add a new trigger.

From there, you can apply the new token to your curls.